Why do we say leshem shamayim
Why do we refer to Hakadosh baruch Hu as 'heaven' in the phrase לשם שמים?
See for example avot 2:2
I'm not sure what else we should say, but is there a reason as to why we say שמים.

I was studying something recently and it mentioned that שמים is a metonym for Hashem

It wasn't this, but found it in Zohar Vayera: ואלו הם שבעים שמות ששולטים על שבעים דרגות תחתונות סוד ויהו"ה. אלו שבעים שמות יהו"ה, סוד שנקרא שמים. שבעה רקיעים הם שעולים לשבעים שמות שם קדוש. וזהו ויהוה המטיר. מאת יהוה מן השמים.

Do we? Where do we do so?

Someone just told me that's why Sefardim say "shamayim" after "birshut"

Avot 2:2 doesn't say that. "וְכָל הָעֲמֵלִים עִם הַצִּבּוּר, יִהְיוּ עֲמֵלִים עִמָּהֶם לְשֵׁם שָׁמַיִם" says "should work with them for the sake of heaven" not "for God's sake"

"Heaven" is universally a synonym of God, as in "Heaven help us!", "Heaven forbid!", "For heaven's sake!", etc.  Maybe we started it.

Are you maybe referring to Pirkei Avot 2:12, כָל מַעֲשֶׂיךָ יִהְיוּ לְשֵׁם שָׁמָיִם?

And if you are thinking of the alternative option I think it would be לשם הקדוש ברוך הוא or לשם השם etc

It is also from Avos 1:11: אַבְטַלְיוֹן אוֹמֵר, חֲכָמִים, הִזָּהֲרוּ בְדִבְרֵיכֶם, שֶׁמָּא תָחוּבוּ חוֹבַת גָּלוּת וְתִגְלוּ לִמְקוֹם מַיִם הָרָעִים, וְיִשְׁתּוּ הַתַּלְמִידִים הַבָּאִים אַחֲרֵיכֶם וְיָמוּתוּ, וְנִמְצָא שֵׁם שָׁמַיִם מִתְחַלֵּל:

These are lots of quotes of the phrase שם שמים but how do you know in any of them שמים refers to God?

@DoubleAA if שמים isnt referring to God, what is it then? Some other diety? An angel? The powers above? Zeus? This is Judaism.

From the sources I bring below, my initial assumption was that this is shorthand for The One Who dwells in shamayim in the manner of השוכן בשמים. Where for shamayim itself, there's the notion of the heavens of the physical universe and also the notion of the metaphysical shamayim. But there are also possibilities that even as early as Tanach, sometimes שמים can be a direct reference to הקב"ה.
Your example of לשם שמים in אבות ב:ב is one of many examples of חז"ל using the term shamayim to refer to G_d directly or to G_d in Heaven.  Here is a list of cases I could find in the Mishna alone:

שם שמים - סנהדרין ו:ד, אבות א:יא, ב:ב,יב, ד:ד,יא, ה:יז
מלכות שמים - ברכות ב:ב,ה
אביו\אביכם\אביהם\אבינו\אביך שבשמים - כלאים ט:ח, יומא ח:ט, ר"ה ג:ח, סוטה ט:טו, אבות ה:כ
(קידשוהו שמים? - ר"ה ב:ז)
בידי שמים - יבמות ד:יג, סנהדרין ט:ו, יא:ה, חולין ג:ב, נגעים יא:ג
של שמים - נדרים ב:ד
נפש\גוף לשמים - נדרים ד:ג
מקדש לשמים - נדרים ה:ו
מן השמים - נדרים י:ו, סנהדרין ב:א, י:א
דיני שמים - ב"ק ו:ד
אלוקינו שבשמים - סנהדרין ז:י
מורה שמים - אבות א:ג, ד:יב
דעתו לשמים - מנחות יג:יא

We also of course have the well-known phrase בסיעתא דשמיא (with Heaven's help) which is a request for G_d's assistance.
When one examines the many usages of the word שמים in Tanach, one can see that the terminology of חז"ל didn't emerge from a vacuum and quite possibly is used in a similar way at a much earlier time to a lesser degree. Here are some of the most relevant examples from the Chumash:

(שמות כ:יח) וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל מֹשֶׁה כֹּה תֹאמַר אֶל בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל אַתֶּם רְאִיתֶם כִּי מִן הַשָּׁמַיִם דִּבַּרְתִּי עִמָּכֶם

(דברים כו:טו) הַשְׁקִיפָה מִמְּעוֹן קׇדְשְׁךָ מִן הַשָּׁמַיִם וּבָרֵךְ אֶת עַמְּךָ אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל וְאֵת הָאֲדָמָה אֲשֶׁר נָתַתָּה לָנוּ כַּאֲשֶׁר נִשְׁבַּעְתָּ לַאֲבֹתֵינוּ אֶרֶץ זָבַת חָלָב וּדְבָשׁ

(דברים לב:מ) כִּי אֶשָּׂא אֶל שָׁמַיִם יָדִי וְאָמַרְתִּי חַי אָנֹכִי לְעֹלָם


Where the first two indicate שמים being the place of G_d's abode (true that He is everywhere and owns all but the earth might be considered a domain that's shared with humans - see later "הַשָּׁמַיִם שָׁמַיִם לַה' והארץ נתן לבני אדם") and in the final one we might have a more direct reference to G_d.
According to Rashi on Devarim 32:40 (mentioned above) near the end of shiras Haazinu, just as a human swears in the name of G_d, G_d Himself can swear by His own name:

אשא ידי אל עצמי בשבועה

Another very important section that contributes to this idea is the tefila that Shlomo Hamelech offers at the time of the inauguration of the בית המקדש in מלכים א, פרק ח:

וַיַּעֲמֹד שְׁלֹמֹה.....וַיִּפְרֹשׂ כַּפָּיו הַשָּׁמָיִם
.....הִנֵּה הַשָּׁמַיִם וּשְׁמֵי הַשָּׁמַיִם לֹא יְכַלְכְּלוּךָ אַף כִּי הַבַּיִת הַזֶּה אֲשֶׁר בָּנִיתִי
..... וְאַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע אֶל מְקוֹם שִׁבְתְּךָ אֶל הַשָּׁמַיִם וְשָׁמַעְתָּ וְסָלָחְתָּ
וְאַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע הַשָּׁמַיִם וְעָשִׂיתָ וְשָׁפַטְתָּ אֶת עֲבָדֶיךָ.....
וְאַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע הַשָּׁמַיִם וְסָלַחְתָּ לְחַטַּאת עַמְּךָ יִשְׂרָאֵל.....
וְאַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע הַשָּׁמַיִם וְסָלַחְתָּ לְחַטַּאת עֲבָדֶיךָ וְעַמְּךָ יִשְׂרָאֵל.....
וְאַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע הַשָּׁמַיִם מְכוֹן שִׁבְתֶּךָ וְסָלַחְתָּ וְעָשִׂיתָ.....
אַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע הַשָּׁמַיִם מְכוֹן שִׁבְתֶּךָ וְעָשִׂיתָ כְּכֹל אֲשֶׁר יִקְרָא אֵלֶיךָ.....
וְשָׁמַעְתָּ הַשָּׁמַיִם אֶת תְּפִלָּתָם וְאֶת תְּחִנָּתָם וְעָשִׂיתָ מִשְׁפָּטָם
וְשָׁמַעְתָּ הַשָּׁמַיִם מְכוֹן שִׁבְתְּךָ אֶת תְּפִלָּתָם וְאֶת תְּחִנָּתָם וְעָשִׂיתָ מִשְׁפָּטָם
וַיְהִי כְּכַלּוֹת שְׁלֹמֹה לְהִתְפַּלֵּל אֶל ה'.....קָם מִלִּפְנֵי מִזְבַּח ה' מִכְּרֹעַ עַל בִּרְכָּיו וְכַפָּיו פְּרֻשׂוֹת הַשָּׁמָיִם

In multiple times here it stresses shamayim as G_d's place and in certain cases such as תשמע השמים one might make that case that this even referring to G_d Himself.
The (ספר הבהיר (סימן ק brings this idea out from tefilas Shlomo with the following:

מנלן דשמים הקדוש ברוך הוא? דכתיב: וְאַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע הַשָּׁמַיִם, אטו שלמה התפלל אל השמים שישמעו תפלתם? אלא אותו שנקרא שמו על השמים, דכתיב: השמים ושמי השמים לא יכלכלוך, הרי שמו של הקדוש ברוך הוא.

Also see the following selected pesukim (among many others) which influence the ideas I have mentioned above:

(ישעיהו סג:טו) הַבֵּט מִשָּׁמַיִם וּרְאֵה מִזְּבֻל קׇדְשְׁךָ וְתִפְאַרְתֶּךָ אַיֵּה קִנְאָתְךָ וּגְבוּרֹתֶךָ הֲמוֹן מֵעֶיךָ וְרַחֲמֶיךָ אֵלַי הִתְאַפָּקוּ
(ישעיהו סו:א) כֹּה אָמַר ה' הַשָּׁמַיִם כִּסְאִי וְהָאָרֶץ הֲדֹם רַגְלָי אֵי זֶה בַיִת אֲשֶׁר תִּבְנוּ לִי וְאֵי זֶה מָקוֹם מְנוּחָתִי
(תהלים יא:ד) ה' בְּהֵיכַל קׇדְשׁוֹ ה' בַּשָּׁמַיִם כִּסְאוֹ עֵינָיו יֶחֱזוּ עַפְעַפָּיו יִבְחֲנוּ בְּנֵי אָדָם
(תהלים קג:יט) ה' בַּשָּׁמַיִם הֵכִין כִּסְאוֹ וּמַלְכוּתוֹ בַּכֹּל מָשָׁלָה
(תהלים קטו:טז) הַשָּׁמַיִם שָׁמַיִם לַה' וְהָאָרֶץ נָתַן לִבְנֵי אָדָם (from this we can see that the earth possesses the shared notion I mentioned above while shamayim is the sole domain of G_d)
(תהלים קכג:א) שִׁיר הַמַּעֲלוֹת אֵלֶיךָ נָשָׂאתִי אֶת עֵינַי הַיֹּשְׁבִי בַּשָּׁמָיִם
(איכה ג:נ) עַד יַשְׁקִיף וְיֵרֶא ה' מִשָּׁמָיִם
(קהלת ה:א) אַל תְּבַהֵל עַל פִּיךָ וְלִבְּךָ אַל יְמַהֵר לְהוֹצִיא דָבָר לִפְנֵי הָאֱלֹהִים כִּי הָאֱלֹהִים בַּשָּׁמַיִם וְאַתָּה עַל הָאָרֶץ עַל כֵּן יִהְיוּ דְבָרֶיךָ מְעַטִּים
(דברי הימים ב ל:כז) וַיָּקֻמוּ הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם וַיְבָרְכוּ אֶת הָעָם וַיִּשָּׁמַע בְּקוֹלָם וַתָּבוֹא תְפִלָּתָם לִמְעוֹן קׇדְשׁוֹ לַשָּׁמָיִם

For further reading, see the discussion here.

Shkoyach for the sources, but the question would then be if Hashem is referred to as shamyim why not just say Hashem, like Leshem Hakadosh Baruch Hu/Hashem, etc? It would be much easier/more clear to understand

Maybe the simple answer is based on the Maharal in Derech Chaim on Pirkei Avot 1:3 who explains that Hashem is referred to as Shamayim because it is distant and above us. Although we are filled with love for Hashem and feel close to him, we need to temper the love with fear and perceive a distance as well.  Therefore the word Shamayim is used to connote a kind of distance and awe. Therefore maybe the same applies for לשם שמים, as however you interpret what it means, the simple meaning is your doing it for "shamyim's" sake which is Hashem, but we don't say "Leshem Hashem" because of the fear and distance that we also have with Hashem.

We do so because of the Rashi on Bereshis 1:1

And a further proof that the heavens and earth were not the first thing created is that the heavens were created from fire (אש) and water (מים), from which it follows that fire and water were in existence before the heavens.

Usually fire either evaporates water and water extinguishes fire. But the Holy NAME is what makes it exist in balance. Fire symbolized midas hadin (judgement), water symbolized midas harachamim (Mercy). It is also related to the saying from Berachos 56b with pot having fire (din) outside and water (hesed) inside

Rabbi Ḥanan said: There are three items seen in dreams that are indications of peace: A river, a bird and a pot. The Gemara elaborates: A river, as it is written: “I will extend peace to her like a river” (Isaiah 66:12); a bird, as it is written: “As birds hovering, so will the Lord of hosts protect Jerusalem” (Isaiah 31:5); and a pot, as it is written: “Lord, You will establish [tishpot] peace for us” (Isaiah 26:12). Peace is likened to a pot which is placed [shafat] on the fire. And Rabbi Ḥanina said: We learned that a pot in a dream is a sign of peace with regard to a pot that does not have meat in it, as a pot that has meat in it symbolizes calamity, as it is stated: “Yea, they chop them in pieces, as that which is in the pot, and as flesh within the cauldron” (Micah 3:3).

I.e. L'shem Shamayim - for the sake of name that keeps everything in balance. It is also a marker of the straight path, which avoids steering to the left (judgement) or to the right (mercy).
